# How to solve 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range' in a two dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting a crash when launching my app 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range'. Full error:

```
Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
2020-07-11 14:04:40.909080+0200 Carrot[13983:705959] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
(lldb)
```

Could anyone give me directions in how I can solve this error? I'm getting the error on this line:

```
return twoDArray[section].items.count
```

This is my full ViewController file:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AddTask, ChangeButton {
    
var sections = FoodData.foodCategories

var twoDArray = [
    Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]), Section(isExpanded: true, items: [Task(name: "No items yet")]),
    ]

// MARK: - TableView data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    
    return twoDArray[section].items.count
}
```

And here is the FoodData struct:

```
struct FoodData {
static let foodCategories = ["New item", "Produce ", "Meat ", "Breakfast ", "Seafood ", "Dairy ", "Frozen ", "Drinks ", "Snacks ", "Grains", "Cans & Jars ", "Spices", "Sauces & Oils", "Paper", "Cleaning", "Personal", "Baking ", "Other"]
```

}

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are setting the number of sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by code you didn’t show. You are returning a too big number in `numberOfSections`.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error after removing that line. `Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
2020-07-11 14:22:59.935032+0200 Carrot[14307:724784] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
(lldb) `

Comment: Show more code. How many sections are you returning?

Comment: It's returning the FoodData categories: `static let foodCategories = ["New item", "Produce ", "Meat ", "Breakfast ", "Seafood ", "Dairy ", "Frozen ", "Drinks ", "Snacks ", "Grains", "Cans & Jars ", "Spices", "Sauces & Oils", "Paper", "Cleaning", "Personal", "Baking ", "Other"]` > 18 sections in total

Comment: Then there’s your problem. Two D Array doesn’t have 18 sections.

Comment: Also “This is my full ViewController file:” No it isn’t. There is more code. Show it.

Comment: Matt, thank you! You are absolutely right, twoDArray didn't have 18 sections. It works perfectly now, thanks a ton.